# Quantifier order for prenex normal form

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

$\exists x R(x) \land \forall y S(y)$ is this equivalent to $\exists x \forall y (R(x) \land S(y))$ as well as $\forall y \exists x (R(x) \land S(y))$?

Is there a rule for the order of pulling out quantifiers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is that you can pull out a quantifier when the term that gets included into its new scope does not have the variable that that quantifier quantifies as a free variable. Formally:

**Prenex Laws**

Where $\varphi$ is any formula and where $x$ is *not* a free variable in $\psi$:

$ \forall x \ \varphi \land \psi \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\varphi \land \psi)$

$ \exists x \ \varphi \land \psi \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\varphi \land \psi)$

As such, you can pull out the existential first, and then the universal, as well as in the other order.

That is:

$\exists x \ R(x) \land \forall y \ S(y) \Leftrightarrow$

$\exists x (R(x) \land \forall y \ S(y)) \Leftrightarrow$

$\exists x \forall y (R(x) \land  S(y))$

But also:

$\exists x \ R(x) \land \forall y \ S(y) \Leftrightarrow$

$\forall y (\exists x (R(x) \land S(y)) \Leftrightarrow$

$\forall y \exists x  (R(x) \land  S(y))$

All equivalences used here follow the general law.

So yes, these are all equivalent.

Comment: I don't understand how $\exists x \forall y (R(x) \land  S(y))$ and
$\forall y \exists x  (R(x) \land  S(y))$ can be semantically equivalent when the first formula asserts of a certain object that a property is fulfilled whilst the second formula doesn't require that. I'm thinking of quantifier scope in sentences like everyone loves a man which can be formalised as $\forall x \exists y (L(x, y) \land man(y))$ or $\exists y \forall x (L(x, y) \land man(y))$.

Comment: @Edward.Lin The crucial difference is that in your example the $x$ and the $y$ are related to each other through the $L(x,y)$ predicate. No such thing is going on with the $R(x)$ and the $S(y)$: they are independent of each other. So yes, you *typically* cannot switch two different quantifiers without changing the meaning of the sentence, because *typically* the two quantified variables depend on each other. But in the case of $\exists x \forall y (R(x) \land S(y))$ they don't depend on each other, and hence in this case you can switch them.